# glfwGetGLVersion fails?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

While attempting to find out what type of OpenGL version I'm using, I followed the suggestion here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017023/cannot-deploy-glfw-3-2)

I have the following code:

```
int major, minor, rev;
glfwGetGLVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL version recieved: %d.%d.%d", major, minor, rev);
```

And I get the following output:

```
OpenGL version recieved: 2130567168.6.0
```

I figured that this was some kind of initialization issue, so I adjusted to the following:

```
int major=0, minor=0, rev=0;
glfwGetGLVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL version recieved: %d.%d.%d", major, minor, rev);
```

And recieved the following output:

```
OpenGL version recieved: 0.0.0
```

I haven't the slightest clue what I'm doing incorrectly here. Any ideas?

**Solved it. I had to place the version query AFTER the OpenGL context was enabled by GLFW.**

That makes sense, but is a little goofy from a learner's perspective, as the context the example linked above suggested using it in order to establish the context in the first place.

Comment: If you figured it out, you should write that in an answer and then accept it, so others can easily find your solution.

Comment: I tried, it said I 'll have to wait 7 hours to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`:

```
const GLubyte *version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
```

Comment: It won't compile as is, hat to change it to a const GLubyte to work. When run, it printed nothing. not 0 or NULL, just...nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the docs. Can you show me what code you're doing to run it?

Comment: If you're using C++, you might need to do a cast of some kind to print out the `char *`, since `ostream` does not have an `operator<<` overload for `GLubyte *` by default.